# Match data.frame to a vector

Tags: r, match

If data such:

```
p <- c(1,2,3,4)
x <- c(2,3,4)
y<-c(10,20,12)
data<-cbind(x, y)

#     x  y
#[1,] 2 10 
#[2,] 3 20 
#[3,] 4 12
```

I want to match x on p, so we have result

```
#     x  y 
#[1,] 0  0 
#[2,] 2 10
#[3,] 3 20
#[4,] 4 12
```

How to match this data following p as control and 0 0 is added because p in first cell not match with first cell of x?

Comment: Start with `data[match(p,data[,"x"]),]`, then set the `NA`s to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base R what we'll do is make a data.frame with three columns, x, y and p where p is the same as x.  Then we'll make another data.frame, key, with just p.  Now we do a merge as a full outer join which will keep all the rows from `data` which don't match `key`.  We are left with a data.frame with three columns, p,x,y where x and y are `NA`.  We replace the `NA` values with 0 and you can then optionally drop the p column.

```
data = data.frame(x,y,p=x)
key = data.frame(p)
result = merge(key,data,by="p",all=T)
result[is.na(result)] = 0
```